# heatmap isn't working

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I followed a sample code to create a fusion tables map with 'heatmap' (hotspots as I called it) but it's not working. Could someone take a look on it, please?

I don't know whether the problem is with some syntax element (but the code didn't break) or with the form element? Another possibility could be that there are just a few points, and it's not possible to produce a heatmap only with that points. But I never heard of such a technical issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #map-canvas { width:500px; height:400px; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var layerl0;
    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "'ENDERECO_GOOGLE'",
          from: 3767057
        },
        map: map
      });
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('heatmap'),
        'click', function() {
         var heatmap = document.GetElementById('heatmap');
         layer.setOptions({
           heatmap: {
             enabled: heatmap.checked
           }
         });
      });           
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  <div>
    <input id="heatmap" type="checkbox" />
    <label>Hotspots</label>
  </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got 2 syntax errors in the file you posted.

```
document.GetElementById();
// must be
document.getElementById();
```

and

```
layer.setOptions()
// must be
layerl0.setOptions()
```

Comment: That's strange.  I downloaded your file, made those two changes and it works fine for me. Porto Alegre Brazil, right? Your map opens at 0,0.

Comment: To me the checkbox still isn't working... I've tried IE, Mozzila and Chrome but the problem persists

Comment: Did you change all occurrences of GetElementById().  There were more than one.

Comment: Yes, I do believe that all those getElementById() are corect now.

Comment: Well what can I say.  Email your new html file and I'll take another look. ebridger at gmri.org

Comment: There was another simple syntax error in your file. layer10 (ten) vs layerl0 (L-zero)